# FirebaseAuthUI crashing App when receiving result of Login Attempt

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I am using FirebaseAuthUi and I keep getting this error when I receive back the request from the Login process:

com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential.

...

Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: The save prompt is disabled for the current app. To restore, remove this app from the "Never save" list in the Smart Lock for Passwords settings for all accounts on this device.

Here is the Code in my Activity result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "SignInFinished");
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(buttonLastPressed){
                loadUserFromDataBase();
            }
            else{
                pushUserToDatabase();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "SignInError");
            if(response == null){
                return;
            }
            // Sign in failed. If response is null the user canceled the
            // sign-in flow using the back button. Otherwise check
            // response.getError().getErrorCode() and handle the error.

            response.getError().printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

The second Log, "SignInError" never shows, so I can't even tell the user that sign in failed.

I am pretty sure I can fix this by going in the settings and changing what the error says, but since the error part never runs, I can't tell the user what went wrong. They return to the activity that launched the login process and there is no indicator that anything has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help someone:

After the signing step, there is a prompt to save the credentials to smart lock.
The crash may occur when you cancel this prompt, because it return the result CANCELED.

if you are not using smart lock in your project or if it is not necessary, you can disable it while configuring your signing methods.

So then you won't get the smart lock prompt and the signing result will directly return as it is (RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCELED etc)

Here is an example on  how to disable smart lock from your firebase project:

```
private final Intent signIn = AuthUI.getInstance()
    .createSignInIntentBuilder().setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
    .build();
```